# Getting absolute rectangle coordinates after direct2d translation and scale

Tags: c++, coordinates, scale, rectangles, direct2d

I'm using direct2d to draw a bitmap (play a video) in a window, and I want to get the **absolute** coordinates for any position in the playing space, whether transformations are applied or not. So if the resolution is 1280x720, then by hovering the cursor over the image, I should get values like `x = 0 ... 1280`, `y = 0 ... 720`.

The positions of the total video area are in the variable `m_rcLiveWindowPos`, while the variable `m_rcDstVideoRect` contains the positions of the actual video *after* adjusting for the aspect ratio. Finally, `m_rcSrcVideoRect` is just the video resolution (ex: left=0, top=0, right=1280, bottom=720).

Below, I applied a translation and then a scale to the `renderTarget`. The `rawScaleFactor` is a number representing the amount to scale the video: if `rawScaleFactor=1`, then the video should be played at 100%. If `2`, then at 200%.

This all works great -- the video zooms in properly and I can click and drag the video around. The problem is that I want to get the absolute x and y coordinates of the video resolution while my cursor is hovering over the video. The first definitions of `mousePosInImage` work for videos with no zoom/panning with the `m_rcDstVideoRect` sitting in a "fitted" position, but the values are incorrect for a zoomed-in video.

```cpp
if (rawScaleFactor != 0)
{
      // Make the dragging more precise based on the scaling factor.
      float dragPosX = (float)m_rawScaleOffsetX / (rawScaleFactor * 2.0f);
      float dragPosY = (float)m_rawScaleOffsetY / (rawScaleFactor * 2.0f);

      D2D1_MATRIX_3X2_F translation = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(dragPosX, dragPosY);

      // Get the center point of the current image.
      float centerPointX = float(m_rcLiveWindowPos.Width()) / 2;
      float centerPointY = float(m_rcLiveWindowPos.Height()) / 2;

      // Calculate the amount that the image must scaled by.
      D2D1ScaleFactor = ((float)m_videoResolution.width / (float)(m_rcDstVideoRect.right - m_rcDstVideoRect.left)) * (float)rawScaleFactor;

      D2D1_MATRIX_3X2_F scale = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale(D2D1::Size(D2D1ScaleFactor, D2D1ScaleFactor),
                                                        D2D1::Point2F(centerPointX, centerPointY));

      // First translate the image, then scale it.
      m_pJRenderTarget->SetTransform(translation * scale);

      int32_t width = ((int32_t)m_videoResolution.width);
      int32_t height = ((int32_t)m_videoResolution.height);

      // This works for non-zoomed in video:
      m_mousePosInImageX = int32_t(width * (rawMousePosX - m_rcDstVideoRect.left) / (m_rcDstVideoRect.right - m_rcDstVideoRect.left));
      m_mousePosInImageY = int32_t(height * (rawMousePosY - m_rcDstVideoRect.top) / (m_rcDstVideoRect.bottom - m_rcDstVideoRect.top));

      // Does not work for all cases...
      m_mousePosInImageX = int32_t((centerPointX * D2D1ScaleFactor) - (centerPointX) + (m_mousePosInImageX / D2D1ScaleFactor));
      m_mousePosInImageY = int32_t((centerPointY * D2D1ScaleFactor) - (centerPointY) + (m_mousePosInImageY / D2D1ScaleFactor));
}

m_pJRenderTarget-> DrawBitmap(m_pJVideoBitmap,
                              m_rcDstVideoRect,
                              1.0f,
                              D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR,
                              m_rcSrcVideoRect);
```

I need a way to "reflect" the changes that SetTransform() did in the `mousePosInImage` variables.

Comment: There are all needed operations on Matrix3x2F. You can invert it or/and use TransformPoint method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1helper/nf-d2d1helper-matrix3x2f-transformpoint if that's what your looking for?

Comment: I don't think that gives me the value I'm looking for. For example, if a certain point in the top left has coordinates (15,10) and that coordinate is the center of, say, a balloon, then after zooming in, if I hover over that same balloon, the coordinates should still be (15,10).

Comment: Thanks, Simon, I figured it out. I had to do a `translation.TransformPoint()` with the two older coordinates of the left-top and right-bottom of `m_rcDstVideoRect`. Then replace those older ones inside of the `m_mousePosInImage` definitions.